# Crash due to delete (trying to handle exceptions...)

Tags: c++, qt, exception, memory, crash

I am writing a program with Qt, and I would like it to show a dialog box with a Exit | Restart choice whenever an error is thrown somewhere in the code.

What I did causes a crash and I really can't figure out why it happens, I was hoping you could help me understanding what's going on.

Here's my `main.cpp:`

```
#include "my_application.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << std::endl;

    My_Application app(argc, argv);

    return app.exec();
}
```

And here's `my_application:hpp`:

```
#ifndef MY_APPLICATION_HPP
#define MY_APPLICATION_HPP

#include <QApplication>

class Window;

class My_Application : public QApplication
{
public:
    My_Application(int& argc, char ** argv);
    virtual ~My_Application();

    virtual bool notify(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event);

private:
    Window *window_;

    void exit();
    void restart();
};

#endif // MY_APPLICATION_HPP
```

Finally, here's `my_application.cpp`:

```
#include "my_application.hpp"
#include "window.hpp"

#include <QMessageBox>

My_Application::My_Application(int& argc, char ** argv) : QApplication(argc, argv)
{
    window_ = new Window;
    window_->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, false);
    window_->show();
}

My_Application::~My_Application()
{
    delete window_;
}

bool My_Application::notify(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event)
{
    try
    {
        return QApplication::notify(receiver, event);
    }
    catch(QString error_message)
    {
        window_->setEnabled(false);

        QMessageBox message_box;
        message_box.setWindowTitle("Error");
        message_box.setIcon(QMessageBox::Critical);
        message_box.setText("The program caught an unexpected error:");
        message_box.setInformativeText("What do you want to do? <br>");

        QPushButton *restart_button = message_box.addButton(tr("Restart"), QMessageBox::RejectRole);
        QPushButton *exit_button = message_box.addButton(tr("Exit"), QMessageBox::RejectRole);

        message_box.setDefaultButton(restart_button);

        message_box.exec();

        if ((QPushButton *) message_box.clickedButton() == exit_button)
        {
            exit();
        }
        else if ((QPushButton *) message_box.clickedButton() == restart_button)
        {
            restart();
        }

    }
    return false;
}


void My_Application::exit()
{
    window_->close();
    //delete window_;

    return;
}

void My_Application::restart()
{
    window_->close();
    //delete window_;

    window_ = new Window;
    window_->show();
    return;
}
```

Note that the line `window_->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, false);` means that `window_` (my main window) won't be deleted when it is closed.

The code I've written above works, but as far as I understand, there's a memory leak: I should uncomment the line `//delete window_;` in `My_Application::exit()` and `My_Application::restart()`. But when I do that, the program crashes when I click restart (or exit but who cares).

(I'm not sure this is useful, in fact it might be misleading, but here's what my debugger tells me: a segmentation fault occurs in `QWidgetPrivate::PaintOnScreen() const` which is called by a function called by a function... called by `My_Application::notify()`)

When I do some `std::cout`s, I notice that the program runs through the entire `restart()` function and in fact through the entire `notify()` function before it crashes.

I have no idea why it crashes. Thanks in advance for your insights!

**Update:**

1. I've noticed that `My_Application::notify()` is called very often. For example, it is called a bunch of times while the error dialog box is open, also *during the execution of the restart function*.
2. The crash actually occurs in the subfunction `QApplication::notify(receiver, event)`. This is not too surprising in light of the previous remark (the receiver has probably been deleted)
3. But even if I forbid the function `My_Application::notify()` to do anything while `restart()` is executed, it still crashes (after having called `My_Application::notify()` a bunch of times, like 15 times, isn't that weird)?

How should I proceed? Maybe I should say (to make the question slightly more relevant) that my class `My_Application` also has a "restore" function, which I've not copied here to try to keep things short. If I just had that restart feature I wouldn't bother too much, but I do want to have that restore feature. I should also say that if I keep the code with the "delete window_" commented, the problem is not only a memory leak, it still crashes sometimes apparently. There must surely be a way to fix this! But I'm clueless, I'd really appreciate some help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using gdb with breakpoints? Most likely, you're trying to delete a pointer that is still in use, causing a segmentation fault. I have a feeling that actually with restarting your program, you should invoke a system command to restart the program in a new process and kill the old process instead of trying to recover the errored process.

Comment: The thing is I wouldn't know where to put breakpoints, since the program leaves `notify()` fine and then crashes. As for your suggestion, you might be right but 1) I'm not sure how I'd do that 2) Still, I don't understand where the error is coming from, I wish I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window_->deleteLater()`.

You are deleting the window when there are still events for it in the event queue; in the output above it looks like a painting command was tried to be delivered after you deleted it.  `deleteLater()` puts a delete command into the queue, so the 'normal' events are delivered *before* the deletion.

Also for clarification, all events pass through `QApplication::notify(..)` - that is why it is called so often, and why it is the central point for exception handling in Qt.